# Disable AJAX in Code coupon

Tags: commerce

hello when I add a promotional code for an order, I must reload the page manually to see appear the discount. How to disable the ajax and page reloads automatically when a code is entered? thank you

Comment: Not completely clear what do you mean by "I must reload the page" - you mean submit the button or literally refresh the page?

Comment: I mean, I have to go on my browser address bar and rafraichier page for the codes are displayed.
When I delete a code, the page is reloaded and removed discount code messages is displayed.
When I add a discount code, the ajax arrow runs but nothing happens. I have to manually reload the page.
I will therefore that ca face as to delete a code. The hen I press "adds a coupon" b the page fully recharge.